# "byte ptr X" as operand in TASM?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, tasm

I have following TASM code:

```
1. mov cx,65535
2. _copy:
3. mov [di], byte ptr 127  ; <---- What does this line do?  
4. mov al, fs:[di]
5. stosb
6. loop _copy
```

What does the third line supposed to do?

What is the difference between

this:

```
mov [di], byte ptr 127
```

this:

```
mov [di], 127
```

and this:

```
mov byte ptr [di], 127
```

There is one more important question: How to convert the original expression

```
mov [di], byte ptr 127
```

to NASM?

Comment: Since the size of the operation can not be deduced you need to specify it. Your assembler may be using some default but that is error prone. Canonical nasm version is `mov byte [di], 127` but `mov [di], byte 127` also works.

Comment: `mov [di], byte ptr 127` and `mov byte ptr [di], 127` both achieve the same thing. I prefer the latter version since it makes more sense to me to speak of a memory operand as a `ptr`, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: Does TASM really accept `byte ptr 127` as an immediate operand, without the `ptr` implying memory?  I just tried the GNU assembler with `mov [rdi], byte ptr 127`, and yes it assembles that (in 64-bit mode) to `c6 07 7f       mov    BYTE PTR [rdi],0x7f`  (canonical disassembly from `objdump -drwC -Mintel`)

Comment: I don't have TASM available on this computer, but MASM gladly accepts `byte ptr 127`, and even mentions in the documentation that `type PTR expression` can be used to _"[force] expression to be treated as having the type specified"_. The TASM 5 manual also mentions this, at least for Ideal mode.